# Change resolution after training (have got a pre-trained model)

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolo

Reading the [YOLOv1 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf), it is mentioned[1] that the first part of the network, that is, those convolutional layers, are first trained at a input resolution of 224x224 on the ImageNet dataset. After that, the model is converted to perform detection, in which the input resolution is increased from 224x224 to 448x448. I am wondering that how can this convertion be done: if the input of the network is at first 224x224, then the number of parameters should differ from that of 448x448, which means that the convolutional layers trained on the ImageNet dataset cannot be reused for detection.

What am I missing here?

[1]: At the end of section "2.2 Training"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the input of the network is at first 224x224, then the number of parameters should differ from that of 448x448

This is your misunderstanding.

The convolution operation has no constraints on the size of the input and thus on the size of the output. When you train a CNN that has fully connected layers at the end for classification, then you're constraining the input to be of a fixed size, because the number of input that a FC layer can accept is fixed.

But, if you remove the classification head from the network and you only use the trained weights of the CNN as a feature extractor, you'll notice that given an input of any dimension (>= the dimension the network has been trained on), the output will be a set of feature maps whose spatial extent increase as the spatial extent of the input increases.

In YOLO, hence, the network is initially trained to perform classificationm with a resolution of 224x224. In this way weights of the convolution operation + the weights of the FC layers at the end learned to extract & classify meaningful features.

After this first training, the FC layers are thrown away and only the feature extraction part is kept. In this way, you can use a good feature extractor, that already learned to extract meaningful features, in a convolutional fashion (ei, producing not a feature vector but a feature map as output, that can be post-processed as YOLO does)

Comment: Also, I've seen your other question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005852/perform-multi-scale-training-yolov2 ) the response and the reason are the same.